# Grouping Python data frame using start date , end date and id columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe contain row_id,id, event_id,EnqueuedTimeUtc,startTime and endtime details.
[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOzE.png)

- In this the startTime and endtime is same for some records.
- The different startTime and endtime represent the main event. and all the other  startTime/endTime in between the main event is sub events.
  Eg: in below pic row id is 4 is a main event and all the sub event's (1-3) time is in between the startTime and endtime of the main event.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUemc.png)

Need to create a single row representation for the main event and subevent's by making event id as columns.
I have tried to group by statement, but didn't achieved  the expected result.
[The required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBTCo.png).
*event id-2 and event id-3 are the total count of each event in sub and main event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pls, don't post your data as images, Simply copy that table and paste as a text here & Secondly pls, add what you have tried with some reproducable examples. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will repost the question as per the guidance